# Suppressing logs from AppClassLoader

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm using the spring-instrument java agent in a console application for load time weaving. The application starts up this way:

```
java -javaagent:/path/spring-instrument-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar -classpath ... com.my.MainClass --argument
```

It's working fine, but it's nicely printing these complementary messages in the stdout that I'd like to avoid:

```
[AppClassLoader@24dbf79d] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.1 built on Saturday Jun 21, 2014 at 00:07:06 GMT
[AppClassLoader@24dbf79d] info register classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@24dbf79d
[AppClassLoader@24dbf79d] info using configuration file:/path/my.jar!/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@24dbf79d] info register aspect org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect
[AppClassLoader@24dbf79d] info register aspect org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect
[AppClassLoader@24dbf79d] info register aspect org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect
[AppClassLoader@24dbf79d] info register aspect org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect
```

I tried configure the log4j level in the command line options, but it seems not working:

```
-Dlog4j.logger.org.aspectj=off
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know Spring, but AspectJ LTW. As the weaver seems to be the same, I guess you also configure it the same way via `META-INF/aop.xml` (or `META-INF/aop-ajc.xml`, respectively).

Maybe you already have such a config file without knowing about it and it says something like

```xml
<weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo">
```

If so, just remove the additional options. The one causing what you have quoted is `-verbose`. See also [AspectJ LTW documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#configuring-load-time-weaving-with-aopxml-files).

Comment: I have only "-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true" in the options. I also tried to explicitly disable it command line, but it didn't help: -Dorg.aspectj.weaver.showWeaveInfo=false -Daj.weaving.verbose=false

Comment: Turned out I had another aop.xml where it set the verbose mode.