# Disable AppClassLoader AspectJ logging with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aspectj

My question is very similar to this one: [Suppressing logs from AppClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25092855/suppressing-logs-from-appclassloader)

The difference is that I'm using AspectJ with Spring Boot (via `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` and `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = ENABLED)` annotations), so I have neither `META-INF/aop.xml`, nor `META-INF/aop-ajc.xml` files, which are mentioned in the answer there.

How do I disable these annoying AppClassLoader warnings with annotation-based configuration?

**Update**
Just to clarify, I'm talking about this kind of logs:

```
...
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.EhCacheCacheConfiguration
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.EhCacheCacheConfiguration
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[AppClassLoader@18b4aac2] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.EhCacheCacheConfiguration
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
...
```

They are printed in red and there's A LOT of them. So I want to suppress these logs somehow.

Comment: Do you want to disable logs from aspectj proxy ?

Comment: @Sambit, I've updated the question with logs sample.

Comment: If you have logback.xml , you can dsiable these loggings from this package org.springframework.cache.ehcache

Comment: No, I don't have this file either.

Comment: Use slf4j and its dependency, use logback.xml, inside logback.xml, supress the logging from the mentioned package. I gave you hints.

Comment: It strikes me that you use both `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` (used for Spring AOP despite its name) and `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = ENABLED)` (used for full AspectJ), i.e. you seem to be using both AOP variants. Without proper configuration this could lead to aspects being woven/activated twice. Maybe you want to decide which AOP variant to use. For the first one you do not need `aop.xml`, for the second one you do. Maybe you want to consult the Spring manual. If this hint helps, let me know and I can turn it into an answer.

Comment: Thanks, you seem to be right, I don't really need `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation, so I removed it. And my aspects still work, even without `aop.xml`. But these annoying logs are still there :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to suppress some of the AspectJ compiler messages while using AspectJ load-time weaving, you can do the following.

Create a copy of the file `aspectjweaver.jar!/org/aspectj/weaver/XlintDefault.properties` to your `resources/META-INF` folder with the name `Xlint.properties`.

Change the line

```
cantFindType = error
```

to

```
cantFindType = ignore
```

Then, create your `aop.xml` in your `resources/META-INF` folder as follows, or add the corresponding option to the `<weaver>` entry as shown:

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN"
        "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-Xlintfile:META-INF/Xlint.properties" />
</aspectj>
```

Now you should have your `cantFindType` errors suppressed, but other AspectJ messages left alone. You can change the reporting of other linter messages similarly.